# Failed to preinstantiate the singleton named org.sakaiproject.accountvalidator.dao.impl.ValidationLogicDaoTarget

Tags: java, tomcat, sakai

Tomcat7 Unable to start sakai 2.9.1. I'm currently using windows xp, tomcat 7.0.59, maven 3, and java 1.6. The startup_err log file(manually created) has got the following errors. Need some help.Thank you.

```
2015-03-16 11:48:10,180 ERROR localhost-startStop-1 org.sakaiproject.util.NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory - Failed to preinstantiate the singleton named org.sakaiproject.accountvalidator.dao.impl.ValidationLogicDaoTarget. Destroying all Spring beans.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sakaiproject.accountvalidator.dao.impl.ValidationLogicDaoTarget' defined in file [C:\opt\tomcat7021\components\accountvalidator-pack\WEB-INF\spring-hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.sakaiproject.springframework.orm.hibernate.GlobalSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sakaiproject.springframework.orm.hibernate.GlobalSessionFactory' defined in file [C:\opt\tomcat7021\components\sakai-kernel-component\WEB-INF\db-components.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Failed to load class path resource [org/sakaiproject/lessonbuildertool/simplepageitem.hbm.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.sakaiproject.util.NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.java:112)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.sakaiproject.util.NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.java:73)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
at org.sakaiproject.component.impl.SpringCompMgr.init(SpringCompMgr.java:160)
at org.sakaiproject.component.cover.ComponentManager.getInstance(ComponentManager.java:98)
at org.sakaiproject.component.cover.ComponentManager.get(ComponentManager.java:107)
at org.sakaiproject.component.cover.ServerConfigurationService.getInstance(ServerConfigurationService.java:52)
at org.sakaiproject.util.RequestFilter.init(RequestFilter.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5542)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sakaiproject.springframework.orm.hibernate.GlobalSessionFactory' defined in file [C:\opt\tomcat7021\components\sakai-kernel-component\WEB-INF\db-components.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Failed to load class path resource [org/sakaiproject/lessonbuildertool/simplepageitem.hbm.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.sakaiproject.util.NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.java:112)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
... 38 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Failed to load class path resource [org/sakaiproject/lessonbuildertool/simplepageitem.hbm.xml]
at org.sakaiproject.springframework.orm.hibernate.impl.AdditionalHibernateMappingsImpl.processConfig(AdditionalHibernateMappingsImpl.java:65)
at org.sakaiproject.springframework.orm.hibernate.AddableSessionFactoryBean.postProcessConfiguration(AddableSessionFactoryBean.java:78)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:727)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
... 49 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:527)
at org.sakaiproject.springframework.orm.hibernate.impl.AdditionalHibernateMappingsImpl.processConfig(AdditionalHibernateMappingsImpl.java:63)
... 54 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:518)
... 55 more
java.lang.Exception: traceback
at     org.sakaiproject.util.NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.java:94)
at org.sakaiproject.util.NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.java:83)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
at org.sakaiproject.component.impl.SpringCompMgr.init(SpringCompMgr.java:160)
at org.sakaiproject.component.cover.ComponentManager.getInstance(ComponentManager.java:98)
at org.sakaiproject.component.cover.ComponentManager.get(ComponentManager.java:107)
at org.sakaiproject.component.cover.ServerConfigurationService.getInstance(ServerConfigurationService.java:52)
at org.sakaiproject.util.RequestFilter.init(RequestFilter.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5542)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:90
```

Comment: Start by upgrading to a newer Sakai and Windows, you're begging for trouble by using old, unmaintained software for an Internet-facing application.

Comment: My workplace doesn't allow me to upgrade to a newer version of OS. Everybody works on WinXP. Will try upgrading to newer sakai and will see.

Comment: Can you install VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

As the log says it can't load `org/sakaiproject/lessonbuildertool/simplepageitem.hbm.xml`

Check whether it exists and has correct structure.

Comment: nothing with that path exists in webapps folder nor in the .m2 repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when installing Sakai 2.9.3 on Linux (so it may not be the same problem after all).  [This message](http://collab.sakaiproject.org/pipermail/sakai-dev/2013-May/022651.html) suggests that the cause is certain `jar` files being loaded by multiple class loaders.  And indeed, I found that my Tomcat 7 tried to load a `commons—dbcp—1.2.2.jar` that comes with Sakai,  but also `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/commons—dbcp.jar`.  I moved one of the two out of the way, but the error only went away (according to my installation log) after I switched from Java 1.6 to Java 7.  You can configure which jar files will be loaded by which class loaders in Tomcat's `conf/catalina.properties`, but Sakai's documentation has a high voodoo factor for me at this point.

Comment: is it possible to make any sort of changes(development) in sakai-src-10, copy it into sakai-demo-10 and make it work ?

Comment: I suppose ... do you experience your problem only with the latter?

Comment: I experience this problem all possible combinations of tomcat 5.5/6/7 , sakai 2.9.x/10.x, maven 2.2.x/3.x.x , Java 6/7.

Comment: Sakai has been deployed successfully.!